# Localization PHP: How can I scan the theme to detect the addition of a new string to be internationalized?

Tags: localization, textdomain

In my theme I added "languages" folder (my-theme/languages/)and in my global css file I have well the text domain. I work only with php internationalization (no javascript).
I don't use plugin for internationalization.

The internationalization currently works fine only for old string added and internationalized.
I have two languages inside "languages": `fr_FR(.po and .mo)`:default lang and `en_GB(.po and .mo)`.

After few weeks I come back to the internationalization and WP can't no more detect new `_e('string', 'text-domain')` or `__('string', 'text-domain')` inside my theme files.

No one .po file display the new string to be internationalized.

Should I use `is_textdomain_loaded('text-domain')` to force WP to scan my theme for new string to be internationalized ?

I created a custom plugin to translate post contents based on `get_locale()` lang. Can there be a conflict with localization/internationalization ?

Does anyone know if this [composer php-scanner](https://packagist.org/packages/gettext/php-scanner) can be adapted for wordpress ?